# Can Vagrantfile use attributes set in .kitchen.yml?

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, vagrantfile, test-kitchen

I am using kitchen to test my chef cookbook.
In .kitchen.yml I use

```
driver:
  name: vagrant
  vagrantfile_erb: Vagrantfile.rb
```

Then in the suites attribute I have

```
attributes: {
  "myattribute" : true,
 ...
```

Can I use this attribute value inside the Vagrantfile.rb? 
I need to run the Vagrantfile with both Kitchen and directly with Vagrant, so I need a way to distinguish between the two methods. I wanted to set a boolean attribute in kitchen like this, but it does not work

```
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  myattribute = "<%= node['myattribute'] %>
  ...
end
```

I get the message

```
Message: Failed to complete #create action: [undefined local variable or method `node' for #<Kitchen::Driver::Vagrant:0x007febf431d138>]
```

Of course an easy solution would be to create 2 different vagrantfile, I just wanted to avoid that

Answer (score 0):

According to the [according README section of kitchen-vagrant](https://github.com/test-kitchen/kitchen-vagrant#-vagrantfile_erb), you should be able to access the attributes in the following way:

```rb
instance.provisioner[:attributes]
```

So I expect that you can access your `myattribute` using

```rb
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  myattribute = instance.provisioner[:attributes][:myattribute]
  ...
end
```

However, explaining the overall plan in a new question might lead to a better solution for your actual problem.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't work with `chef` yet. However, you could load you `.yml` like this in your `Vagrantfile`:

```
require 'yaml'
set = YAML.load_file(ENV['DEVOPS_HOME'] + '/vagrant/server/settings.yml')
```

And then you could load the variable:

```
  ..
  vagrant.vm.define "dev.database", autostart: false do |dev|
    database = set['dev']['server']['database']
    vm = set['dev']['vm']
    dev.vm.box = vm['box']
    ..
```

Comment: That wouldn't work in my case, since I want vagrant to run some lines just when it's used by .kitchen and not doing a vagrant up. So if that attribute is set then execute this additional lines, otherwise not. I will update the question to make it clear